# PHP Query set combobox for another combobox

Tags: php, mysql

how to fix this syntax for this logic ?
i want to select my select option to select the another select option

```
    <?php
    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $query_string1 = "SELECT * FROM suppliers where ProductID = // firstSelectoption(value)";
    $query_string2 = "SELECT * FROM categories";

    $query = mysql_query($query_string);
    $query1 = mysql_query($query_string1);
    $query2 = mysql_query($query_string2);
    ?>
```

and in the body i make

```
    <select name="first" id="first" onchange="childrenOnChange(this.value)">
         <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo '<option value=' . $row["ProductID"] . '>';
                echo $row['ProductID'];
                echo '</option>';
            }
          ?>
     </select>

     <select name="second" id="second">
            <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
                echo '<script>';
                echo 'var arr = array(';
                $row['SupplierID'] . ',';
                echo ')';
                echo '</script>';
            }
            ?>
     </select>
```

i want to set the second select option value with $query1;

Comment: PHP is server side so it is not available once the page has loaded. You will need to use AJAX for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853870/how-to-implement-chained-select-using-mysql-php-and-query

Answer (score 0):

If you get the value from the query with `$val = mysql_fetch_array($query1)`, then you can include the following in your loop:

```
$selected = '';
if ($row['ProductID'] == $val) {
    $selected = "selected";
}

echo '<option value="'.$row['ProductID'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$row['ProductID'].'</option>';
```

Comment: Side note: `mysql_query` is deprecated, I would suggest switching to PDO prepared statements (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).